# action_dispatch.request.parameters are not being populated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, request, parameters, actioncontroller

I have an API sending my app requests, and the Request Payload in my Google Chrome Debugger seems populated with data that *should* have populated my ActionDispatch Request Parameters, so that within the controller, I could call `params`, and it would draw the items found in my request payload.

**My request payload**

`stateId=resume&Authorization=&Expires=1427487450&registration%5Fid=3&member%5Fid=1&Signature=wiXiEskkMFTsOQh9vsRg%3D&Content%2DType=application%2Fjson&X%2DExperience%2DAPI%2DVersion=1%2E0%2E1&agent=null&&activityId=http%3A%2F%2F6LHIJumrnmV%5Fcourse%5Fid&content=1k21098100101100002000`

So I should be able to call `params['stateId']` or `params['member_id']`, but my params are empty. What process has to happen inbetween the Request Payload ( or simply called Form Data ), and Rails picking it up and distributing those variables as `params` ?